# Pass through touch events on React Native

Tags: react-native, touch, overlay, touch-event

We built a React Native tablet kiosk app which displays multiple pages of input fields to a user at a front desk. The user has to fill out all the forms and can send them at the end.

Users can just walk away from the kiosk at any time, which would result in their last screen being the "welcome screen" for the next user. To avoid that, the app resets after some time if there was no user interaction (any touch event on the screen).

Right now, we use a countdown and reset it on each input field, button and background touch there is. This results in passing the reset callback to a lot of components. It works, but it is just a lot of redundancy and can lead to errors easily.

Is there any way, we can add an overlay to the very top of the view, which can catch all touch events and call the reset callback, but also pass the touch event to the views below? So when a user clicks on a button, the overlay calls the its callback but also the button is clicked (same for input fields, etc).

We also tried the Gesture Responder System, but could not get the touch event to pass through - it was always consumed by the component with the Gesture Responder System.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try adding a [`pointerEvents`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#pointerevents) attribute to your `View`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. I had to set `pointerEvents` to `box-none`. After that, the `onTouchStart` callback is called and the tap is also handled by the children of the view.

Comment: @gtRfnkN could you provide details on the final solution you found? I'm trying to do the exact same thing and the onTouchStart is never called if I set on that same view the `pointerEvents` to `box-none`.

Comment: Make sure to add the `pointerEvents` and `onTouchStart` to a view that wraps your whole app and not on an overlay.

If you put it on an overlay view it won't work. The overlay will pass the touches through but `onTouchStart` will not be called.